# Vaadin: Reduce package.json to the only used dependencies in production mode

Tags: vaadin, package.json, blackduck

We're using in our project BlackDuck from Synopsis to identify the licenses of our used dependencies. There is actualy an small issue with Vaadin: When we build the frontend - based on Vaadin Core - in production mode the package.json is stuffed with a lot more dependencies than we use. And it includes also features from the pro-version. Since the detect-script for BlackDuck scans this package.json we get a lot of "false-positives". So is there a way of reducing the package.json to the only required dependencies by creating the build via Vaadin? As far as i could see the package.json will be always overwritten, when starting the build. Of course i can "hack" the package.json afterwards with a script, but this is not the way i look for.
Here is our profile for creating the "production ready" frontend sources:

```
        <profile>
        <id>production-mode</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Instead of using vaadin-core you can include only the components you need inside the maven / pom configuration. This should also clean up your package.json

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This response was based on speculation rather than how things actually work.

The dependencies that Vaadin generates into `package.json` are based on the Java dependencies that are defined through Maven or Gradle.

If you want to have all the free components but want to avoid the commercial ones, then you can just change the `com.vaadin:vaadin` dependency to `com.vaadin:vaadin-core`. If you want to be even more granular, then you can either exclude the ones you don't want or build your own platform by including  only the things you think you need out of the dependencies listed in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-core/23.0.8.

Comment: I'm using `vaadin-core` and don't have any Pro components in my Maven dependencies, but @vaadin/grid-pro etc. are still in the package.json.

Comment: Same for Gradle (with springboot starter, that only shows vaadin-core in deps); At least grid-pro is in a freshly created 23 Gradle project package.json

Comment: Sounds like a bug possible caused by the addition of @vaadin/bundle to pin the packages in v23

Comment: Sorry, seems like I was making assumptions about how I expected things to be without actually verifying that things work out in that way. I would definitely see this is a bug, and it might very well be related to the new bundle mechanism.